# why redirect in zend FW2 results to redirect loop

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2

I'm trying to redirect from Action to another action in same controller, here is the code:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function doAction()
    {
        var_dump('doAction');die;
    }
public function indexAction()
    {
     return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application',array('controller'=>'index','action' => 'do'));
    }
}
```

but in chrome browser says "This web page has redirect loop"
I tried to redirect to completely other controller:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application',array('controller'=>'auth','action' => 'login'));
```

but the same result.
***NOTE:*** I was changed the route in module.config.php from /application to /v1
and this is part I made a change in:

```
'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/v1',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

is it the reason? (tried to replace v1 with application like default, but no change in result )

why can't I make redirect to action?
any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: this worked for me `return $this->forward()->dispatch("Application\Controller\Index", array("action" => "do"));`
but still don't know why redirect not working ..

Comment: You need to figure out what the loop is - what URL is the browser redirecting to? Check the headers (e.g. the networking tab in Chrome) to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application/default',array('controller'=>'index','action' => 'do'));
```

As your code isn't using the child route which allows you to override the controller / action

Comment: Thank you @Tom, this worked for me. but didn't understand the reason and the meaning of `application/default` . can you explain what happened to us?

Comment: Basically if you look at your array above you first key is "application" so when adding this into the redirect route it has access to the route "v1". As you defined the controller and action inside the child route of "default" you have to access it via a "/". So when using "application/default" it will have access to the route "v1/[:controller[/:action]]" allowing you to override the params